# Avoid duplicates during the Join operation in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have couple of Date tables like the below

***Date1 (Stores Discount Dates for each Model)***

```
Year    Model   DiscountDate
2018    99L263  1/1/2017
2018    99L263  1/8/2018
2018    99L263  5/24/2018
```

***Date2 (Stores Price Dates for each Model)***

```
Year    Model   PriceDate
2018    99L263  1/1/2017
2018    99L263  1/8/2018
2018    99L263  3/1/2018
```

I am trying to find all the Discount & Price dates for each model. It leads to Cartesian product.

```
 SELECT D1.Year
    ,D1.Model
    ,D1.DiscountDate
    ,D2.PriceDate
FROM Date1 D1
INNER JOIN Date2 D2 ON D1.Year = D2.Year
    AND D1.Model = D2.Model
```

I am getting an output like this

```
Year    Model   DiscountDate    PriceDate
2018    99L263  1/1/2017    1/1/2017
2018    99L263  1/1/2017    1/8/2018
2018    99L263  1/1/2017    3/1/2018
2018    99L263  1/8/2018    1/1/2017
2018    99L263  1/8/2018    1/8/2018
2018    99L263  1/8/2018    3/1/2018
2018    99L263  5/24/2018   1/1/2017
2018    99L263  5/24/2018   1/8/2018
2018    99L263  5/24/2018   3/1/2018
```

***My expected output is***

```
Year    Model   DiscountDate    PriceDate
2018    99L263  1/1/2017    1/1/2017
2018    99L263  1/8/2018    1/8/2018
2018    99L263  5/24/2018   3/1/2018
```

I have not included discount date in Join condition since I can't Join with date since it may or may not match each other.

Comment: try in query Group by DiscountDate

Comment: @Vipul, `group by` is used for aggregation, why do you think OP needs to aggregate?

Comment: Are these _all_ the columns in your table? There is no column to match the final row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is not really in the format of a relational table.  The columns don't have any relationship to each other.  But, you can do what you want using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select year, model,
       max(discountdate) as discountdate,
       max(pricedate) as pricedate
from ((select year, model, discountdate, null as pricedate
              row_number() over (partition by year, model order by pricedate) as seqnum
       from discounts
      ) union all
      (select year, model, null, pricedate,
              row_number() over (partition by year, model order by pricedate) as seqnum
       from prices
      )
     ) pd
group by year, model, seqnum;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte1 as
(Select *, Row_Number() over (partition by year, model order by DiscountDate) as ranking from date1)
, cte2 as
(Select *, Row_Number() over (partition by year, model order by pricedate) as ranking from date2)
 SELECT D1.Year
    ,D1.Model
    ,D1.DiscountDate
    ,D2.PriceDate
FROM cte1 D1
INNER JOIN cte2 D2 ON D1.Year = D2.Year
    AND D1.Model = D2.Model AND D1.ranking = D2.ranking
```

Comment: Doesn't that need a full join? I mean what if there are more, say discounts than prices?

Comment: It'll if that's the case. OP hasn't discussed that

Comment: @AjayGupta.. tell me your result, when `Date2` has 4 rows?

Comment: In that case, we don't get that row. As stated before, the OP hasn't discussed any such case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my case for each model, I might have get more rows in either table1 or table2. The query should work. I will vote up for your approach.

Answer (score 1):

If pricedate is the date datatype then you can use a sub-query, instead of a join, to get the desired output.  The example below, should return the desired output.

```
 SELECT D1.Year
       ,D1.Model
       ,D1.DiscountDate
       ,(SELECT MAX(D2.PriceDate)
           FROM Date2 D2
          WHERE D2.Model = D1.Model
            AND D2.Year = D1.Year
            AND D2.PriceDate <= D1.DiscountDate
        ) AS PriceDate
   FROM Date1 D1
```